# How to close/cancel camera roll/image gallery using react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-image-crop-picker

I'm implementing `react-native-image-crop-picker` in my app and I'm able to open it and pick images but I don't see a way to cancel out of it or close it -- see below:

[image]

Once the camera roll/image gallery opened, I want to give the user a way to cancel out of it or close it. How do I do that?

I open the image picker simply by calling this function:

```
const pickImage = () => {
   ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 400,
      height: 250,
      cropping: true
    }).then(image => {
      onFilePicked(image);
    });
```